# Does the meaning change? To / In order to

Tags: meaning-in-context, infinitive-clauses

> The manager sent Mike to Japan to receive some training.

In this sentence, I think it's Mike who receives some training .

But if I change the sentence to:

> The manager sent Mike to Japan in order to receive some training.

Does the sentence still have the same meaning as above,
or this time it is the manager who receives some training?

Comment: The both have the same meaning and strictly speaking they are both ambiguous. The more salient interpretation is that it was Mike who was intended to receive some training.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you, but can it be argued that the understood subject of the infinitive is **The manager** instead of **Mike**?

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are of the form "subject - verb - object". "The manager" is the subject; "sent" is the verb; "Mike" is the object (the one being sent), and the remainder of the sentence refers to the object (Mike).

The phrase "sent ... in order to..." makes sense grammatically, as does "sent ... to ...". Both cases refer back to the object of the verb "to send", that is, both refer to Mike.

An alternative is "The manager sent Mike to receive some training in Japan." All of them are correct. But this time "in Japan" refers to the training being received, and the training is the reason Mike is being sent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , but why can't one say it's the manager  who is sent to receive some training?

Comment: The verb "to send" is a transitive verb, meaning it takes action on an object. The subject (the manager) causes the action but is not part of the action. "The manager sent himself" or "the manager sent herself" or "Mike sent the manager" would all be sending the manager to receive the training.